# Loging into a site using a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, curl, xmlhttprequest

I am learning curl and XMLHttpRequests i am trying to login to my telecom account, i have tried CURL and it works on other sites but i haven't been able to work this here is my code, please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

         var toSend = {
                 _form_url:,       //I took these params from capturing the request.
                 _success_url:,
                 _failure_url:,
                 msisdn:username,
                 password:"password"

         }

             var JSONstring = JSON.stringify(toSend);

             var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

             xhr.open('POST','https://www.three.co.uk/cs/form/customer-my3-login');

             xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');

            xhr.Send(JSONstring);








</script>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, if you're learning, it's better to use documented API to be sure what you're doing is possible. Here is a list of some public APIs https://github.com/n0shake/Public-APIs

Moreover, the method for the xhr is probably `send` with a capital letter, and giving the full request/response from a browser will probably give more context to help. We don't know if it's an ajax request or a form POST to login on this site.

Comment: thanks for replying, its  a post method with conent-type application/json with a AJAX object request body